# Associated points of Spec $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/ I$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, affine-schemes

Suppose we know that the only associated points of 
Spec $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/ I$ were
$[(y-x^2)]$, $[(x-1,y-1)]$ and $[(x-2,y-2)]$. Is there enough information
to deduce if this scheme is reduced or not?
I have been thinking about it, but I am confused. I would appreciate 
any comments/hints. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reduced ring has no embedded primes, see here: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031O

But your ring has.

Comment: Right. Of course! $[(x-1, y-1)]$ is an embedded point! Would you happen to know if it is possible to know if the scheme is reduced at $[(x-2, y-2)]$ or not by the information given?

Comment: No you cannot deduce anything about that. The irreducible component of that point could be the point itself. You have no information, whether this is a reduced point or a thick point.